# Using mod_rewrite to redirect non-existent subdomain to home page

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have searched all over this site and the web and still I cannot get this right. I have many URLs like  this: http://archives.cancunandrivieramaya.com/archives/cancun.cgi/md/read/id/XXXX that I want to redirect to the home page http://www.cancunandrivieramaya.com/. The subdomain no longer exists. How do I write the mod-rewrite to redirect the subdomain with wildcard characters at the end to the homepage? This is one of the 100's that don't work :(

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.cancunandrivieramaya\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^archives\.cancunandrivieramaya\.com([a-z0-9]+)\
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.cancunandrivieramaya.com/[L,QSA]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Thanks to this article by Altaf Khatri http://www.altafkhatri.com/Technical/Configure/How-to-publish-or-host-subdomain-on-winhostcom/Solution-resolution I was able to follow his step-by-step instructions for setting up the subdomain on WinHost, then I added this rule to the web.config file:

```
<rule name="archive redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.archives\.cancunandrivieramaya\.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.cancunandrivieramaya.com/" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="archives 2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?archives\.cancunandrivieramaya\.com$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/archives/($|/)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.cancunandrivieramaya.com/" />
        </rule>
```

Works perfectly!